# Required adjustments for stressed yield curves

Tags: interest-rates, yield-curve, no-arbitrage-theory, stress-testing

I was looking at [Basel proposed](https://www.bis.org/basel_framework/chapter/SRP/31.htm?inforce=20190101#paragraph_SRP_31_20190101_31_90) interest rate shocks. Using the standard US Treasury Yield Curve for the period starting from September 2017 to August 2019, I was able to construct Steep and Flat scenarios as highlighted in the link above. In general, they do make sense given the current yield curve for US Treasuries:

[image: Pic]

My question now is what further adjustments do these stressed curves need? One subject that comes to mind is the "no arbitrage-ness" of the curve. Do I have to make sure that the curve does not present arbitrage opportunity? If so, how?

Any other adjustments that I need to make sure before feeding the stressed yields to valuation models and regression models with other risk factors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question now is what further adjustments do these stressed curves need? One subject that comes to mind is the "no arbitrage-ness" of the curve. Do I have to make sure that the curve does not present arbitrage opportunity? If so, how?

No there is no such thing as arbitrage arising from a risk free zero curve. Any zero rate you get is by definition the risk free rate. Same for the implied forward rates.

> Any other adjustments that I need to make sure before feeding the stressed yields to valuation models and regression models with other risk factors?

I am not familiar with your specific regulation. From what I know of similar market risk regulations for insurances: you should just have to apply what is precisely described in that link. Applying any change to that would not be deemed compliant with the prescribed scenario. Note that this may not make sense... as these regulatory choices are often political and not based on facts. In some specific regulation you have to only apply a shock to one “bucket” of maturities at a time; so you are still lucky to have continuous zero curve :)

Comment: good to know that no arbitrage test is not required. Let's assume that this is for an unregulated financial institute. There is no hard requirement as to the buckets, that is why I was using the standard US Treasury rates instead of 19 or whatever number of buckets as specified by Basel. How would you use the flexibility of not being regulated in this context?

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: The goal is to correctly shock the yield curve and propagate the shock to other asset classes (equity, FX, spread).

Comment: Do you mean reprice a book based on the shocked curve? Or also shocking other risk-factors?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear -- 1) shock the yield curves; 2) propogate the shock to other risk factors; 3) reprice the book using the shocked yield curve and its effect on other risk factors.

Comment: I am not familiar with the methodology that you are referring to. I am only used to completely economically specified stress scenarios. In general, what is interesting imho with stress tests is that they do not relate to the historical-calibrated risk engine that you use or to other calibrated parameters. In that sense it gives an “orthogonal” view to your risk model. Again imho this is even more important because the last 10years were quite special economically speaking (recovery). So in your correlations you may get things such as positive correlation btw rates and asset prices.

Comment: What will certainly not be the case under certain “stressed” situtions (e.g brexit, huge rate increase, etc). Reasoning in this way would also allow you to better understand some weaknesses in the portfolio without relying on a single distribution of your risks. Again imho a simple risk engine can not capture everything (you are blind to what you don’t calibrate to). Don’t get me wrong, neither would stress testing in general, but the process of thinking that way is also important.